# How correctly get a change of the child component of the parent?

Tags: typescript, angular, event-handling

I have nested components of the following construction:

```
app.parent.component > app.container.component > app.containeritem.component
```

For example:

**app.parent.component**

```
import ...
@Component({
    selector:'parent',
    template: '<container></container>,
    ....
})
```

**app.container.component**

```
import ...
@Component({
    selector: 'container',
    template: '<containeritem></containeritem>',
    ...
})
```

**app.containeritem.component**

```
import ...
  @Component({
        selector: 'containeritem',
        template: `<ul><li draggable="true"(dragend)="update.emit($event)">lorem</li></ul>`
        ...
    })
```

Inside `app.child.component` i emitting **drag** action. So, how i can correctly get action data of **app.containeritem.component** in **app.parent.component**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just pass the event up with `Output`s and `EventEmitter`s:

**app.parent.component**

```
import ...
@Component({
    selector:'parent',
    template: '<container (onDrag)="doSomething($event)"></container>,
    ....
})
export class ParentComponent {
    doSomething(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

**app.container.component**

```
import ...
@Component({
    selector: 'container',
    template: '<containeritem (onDrag)="onDrag.emit($event)"></containeritem>',
    ...
})
export class ContainerComponent {
    @Output onDrag: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
}
```

**app.containeritem.component**

```
import ...
@Component({
    selector: 'containeritem',
    template: `<ul><li draggable="true"(dragend)="onDrag.emit($event)">lorem</li></ul>`
    ...
})
export class ContainerItemComponent {
    @Output onDrag: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Comment: Thx! I'm just so imagined, but I doubt that it is good practice

Comment: How is it not good practice? That's the only way to pass events up the component levels. You could however make yourself a service with a `Subject` where you push those events and everyone can subscribe to it.